# In a existing spring-boot application, run a infinite loop in a seperate thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous, executorservice

I have a existing spring-boot service(hosting many apis) with following main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BusinessRules {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BusinessRules.class, args);
    }
}
```

As a new requirement, I need to consume SQS messages from two different SQS queues in separate threads(via infinite loop) within this same service. Can I simply add new two new thread using ExecutorService. Something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BusinessRules {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BusinessRules.class, args);
        //new code
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Runnable runnable1 = new SQSMessageProcessor1(); //infinite loop in run method
        Runnable runnable2 = new SQSMessageProcessor2(); //infinite loop in run method
        executor.execute(runnable1);
        executor.execute(runnable2);
    }
}
```

Are there any issues with the above code or any other better alternatives available.

Comment: Just a question: wouldn't it be possible to just use some JMS Listeners so new messages get forwarded to your consumer immediately? Then you don't need polling :-)

Comment: Polling is kind of hard-core requirement in present context.

Answer (score 2):

In general, spring offers support for async jobs (full documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class MyApp {

    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }

}

public class MyBean { 

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
    public void doSomething() {
        // something that should execute periodically
    }

}
```

For your particular use case, you should probably use spring built-in messaging: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/1.2.x/multi/multi__messaging.html

The main issue with your current code is that it will be out of control of spring: context restart/stop, monitoring, dependency injection etc

Comment: So I will have three main classes(one existing and two) with ```@SpringBootApplication``` annotation and both the new will ```@EnableAsync``` and ```@EnableScheduling``` annotation?

Comment: I have one more question. What would be order between new Async app and older non-async app(one with the main).

Comment: This should be the same spring boot application, no need to split it